# Angular service worker URLs

Tags: angular, progressive-web-apps

I have configured an Angular service worker and want it to cache external API data for certain paths (GET requests).

This is the configuration:

```
datagroups: [
   {
      "name": "backend-data",
      "urls": ["https://backend.ourserver.com/data/currencies"],
      ...
   }
]
```

The caching seems to work fine when providing the full URL, however when using "/data/currencies" or "/data/***" or even "https://backend.ourserver.com/data/**" it does not seem to work.

How can the urls be written so that a wildcard or pattern would work?

Thanks!
Thomas

Comment: Do you also specify the `cacheConfig` in your dataGroup?

Answer (score 2):

You should try:

```
"urls": ["/data/**"],
```

this should match every url after the given prefix.

Comment: But why would it be necessary to specify the host? [In my angular app](https://github.com/MintPlayer/MintPlayer/blob/master/MP.Web/ClientApp/ngsw-config.json#L31) I only specify the url, similar as stated in the question, and it works fine.

Comment: Yep should work and its better without the host. I corrected my answer.